# Node.js: How to send headers with form data using request module?

Tags: node.js, header, request, form-data

I have code like the following:

```
var req = require('request');

req.post('someUrl',
   { form: { username: 'user', password: '', opaque: 'someValue', logintype: '1'}, },
   function (e, r, body) {
      console.log(body);
});
```

How can I set headers for this?
I need user-agent, content-type and probably something else to be in the headers:

```
headers = { 
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36',
   'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
};
```

I've tried in multiple ways but I can either send header or form-data, failed to send both.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

I've finally managed to do it.
Answer in code snippet below:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var request = require('request');

var form = {
    username: 'usr',
    password: 'pwd',
    opaque: 'opaque',
    logintype: '1'
};

var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
var contentLength = formData.length;

request({
    headers: {
      'Content-Length': contentLength,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    uri: 'http://myUrl',
    body: formData,
    method: 'POST'
  }, function (err, res, body) {
    //it works!
  });
```

Comment: throw new Error('undefined is not a valid uri or options object.') ^

Error: undefined is not a valid uri or options object.
    at request (C:\Users\pjt\node_modules\request\index.js:44:11)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\pjt\routes\payment.js:170:11)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\pjt\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pjt\node_modules\request\request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)

Comment: This didn't work for me where the answer below which just sets an object to form did.

Comment: its deprecated
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 55):

This should work.

```
var url = 'http://<your_url_here>';
var headers = { 
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
};
var form = { username: 'user', password: '', opaque: 'someValue', logintype: '1'};

request.post({ url: url, form: form, headers: headers }, function (e, r, body) {
    // your callback body
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but seems in this case form data is not sent in a proper way. I have almost the same code in .Net and in case form data is sent I should not have login form in body and should have token. I'll post it here soon, probably it will help

Comment: `request` is deprecated...
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 21):

I think it's just because you have forgot **HTTP METHOD**. The default HTTP method of request is GET.

You should add `method: 'POST'` and your code will work if your backend receive the post method.

```
var req = require('request');

req.post({
   url: 'someUrl',
   form: { username: 'user', password: '', opaque: 'someValue', logintype: '1'},
   headers: { 
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36',
      'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
   },
   method: 'POST'
  },

  function (e, r, body) {
      console.log(body);
  });
```

Comment: This is a better answer as it does not rely on stringify which makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution to this problem and It should work. I'm sure about this because I also faced the same problem

> here is my solution----->

```
var request = require('request');

//set url
var url = 'http://localhost:8088/example';

//set header
var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Your authorization'
};

//set form data
var form = {first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name};

//set request parameter
request.post({headers: headers, url: url, form: form, method: 'POST'}, function (e, r, body) {

    var bodyValues = JSON.parse(body);
    res.send(bodyValues);
});
```

Comment: i edited my answer please see and then say if any issue in that. thank you

Comment: your answer is right and helped me too, but try to implement short code which explain the solution only

Answer (score 6):

Just remember set method to POST in options. Here is my code

```
var options = {
    url: 'http://www.example.com',
    method: 'POST', // Don't forget this line
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-MicrosoftAjax': 'Delta=true', // blah, blah, blah...
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36',
    },
    form: {
        'key-1':'value-1',
        'key-2':'value-2',
        ...
    }
};

//console.log('options:', options);

// Create request to get data
request(options, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) {
        //console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('body:', body);
    }
});
```