# Puppeteer: How do I download a file using chrome headless browser api?

Tags: web-scraping, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

Using Puppeteer, how do I get the headless chrome browser to download a file (or make additional http requests and save the response)?

Comment: An API in Puppeteer is on its way (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/299), however Headless Chrome needs to support downloads first. There's an open bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481.

Comment: Chrome headless support is almost there: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/590913

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

const response = await axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: href,
  responseType: 'stream',
})
const writer = fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve(`${__appRootDir}/public/${fileName}`))
response.data.pipe(writer)
writer.on('finish', async () => {
  try {
    console.log('File downloaded');
    await browser.close()
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in finish callback:', error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tool I wrote to download all the resources that a page uses upon load.

> This node command-line utility uses a headless browser (Puppeteer) to render a webpage and download all resources it may need. These resources including the original HTML are all saved locally...

https://github.com/stav/wgrep

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the Chrome DevTools protocol for that.

For the entire browser ([docs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Browser/#method-setDownloadBehavior)):

```js
const browserClient = await browser.target().createCDPSession()

await browserClient.send('Browser.setDownloadBehavior', {
  behavior: 'allow',
  downloadPath: './downloads',
})
```

For a single page ([docs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-setDownloadBehavior)):

```js
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
  behavior: 'allow',
  downloadPath: './downloads',
});
```

---

##### Note

According to the documentation, `Page.setDownloadBehavior` is deprecated.

And since `Page._client` is not documented, the best way to enable downloads is to use `Browser.setDownloadBehavior`.

Answer (score -1):

You could make a simple request through the window, it should work.
[npm request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

As soon as it returns the promise with your response, you could write an express Save function, and store the response.

It seems that puppeteer it has this implementation. See here:
[How to make a request with puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-request).

Have a look over this:

*Emitted when a page issues a request. The request object is read-only. In order to intercept and mutate requests, see page.setRequestInterceptionEnabled.*

I hope this helps.

[Link for setting headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121846/node-js-how-to-send-headers-with-form-data-using-request-module)

Comment: I would love to be able to just use node to automate downloading files. The problem with just making a regular http request in node is that it will not  send the proper session cookies that are being managed by the headless browser. Using a full headless browser makes the task easier due to the extra functionality that it provides.

Comment: What you need is headers. I just edited my response, showing an example on how to add headers. this way, regardless of your browser, the sessions are being stored, and the client will get a notification that a browser(defined in header) is trying to do an action. In your case, to download the files.

Comment: That mechanism will let you look at requests being made (and alter them). I want to trigger additional requests that would not otherwise be made and save the response to disk.

Comment: just add another function as parameter. or validation. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you please give a specific example? How do I make an http request inside the context of the chrome headless browser environment or the wrapper: Pupperteer?