# How to send bearer token and x-www-form-urlencoded data using Node Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, node-request, npm-request

I want to replicate this Postman call using the node module [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). See screenshots.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WMqQ.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GRT1.png)

As shown in screenshot, in my request, I need to pass a `bearer token` as well as `x-www-form-urlencoded` values. I tried following the top 2 answers from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121846/node-js-how-to-send-headers-with-form-data-using-request-module) but with no success.

I have basically tried doing

```
let form = {
    "field1": value1,
    "filed2": value2
};

let headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
}

request.post({ url: "https://myapp.net/myendpoint", form: form, headers: headers }, function(err, res, success){
    console.log(success);
});
```

and also

```
let form = {
    "field1": value1,
    "field2": value2
};

var formData = querystring.stringify(form);

let options = {
    uri: "https://myapp.net/myendpoint",
    method: 'POST',
    auth: {
        'bearer': token
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: formData
};


request.post(options, function(err, res, success){
    console.log(success);
});
```

Can someone please show the right way to do it?

**EDIT**:
To clarify: the result of these requests is 400 status. I would get 400 on Postman as well if I was sending `form-data`, but if I send `x-www-form-urlencoded` then it would succeed in postman. I don't know how to do this in request.

Comment: What does the request look like? What's telling you that this isn't working? Do you have an error message or something?

Comment: 400 unauthorized status @joshuakcockrell

Comment: Which means it's hitting the server, but the interesting part is I would get 400 on postman as well if I was sending `form-data`, and if I send `x-www-form-urlencoded` then it would succeed in postman. I don't know how to do this in `request`

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have control over the server or else you would know more than just a 400 error. Try sending this request to https://httpbin.org/post and it will show you how your request looks to a server. Compare that to a postman request sent to httpbin. This will at least narrow down the problem for you. A 400 error code is pretty generic so you need more info here.

Comment: Try to skip content-type and use `form: { "field1": value1, "field2": value2 }` instead of body and stringify..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
let options = {
    uri: "https://myapp.net/myendpoint",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    form: {
        "field1": value1,
        "field2": value2
    };
};

request.post(options, function(err, res, success){
    console.log(success);
});
```

The content type should be set automatically